# Unable to load RealmSwift using Cocoa pods

Tags: realm, cocoapods-1.1.1

I am using Xcode 8.1. I'm trying to install RealmSwift in my project using Cocoa Pods. Cocoa Pods version is 1.1.1. However, I'm getting the following error:
`Unable to find a specification for 'RealmSwift'`

The contents of my Podfile are given below:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Validator' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'RealmSwift'

 end

  # Pods for Validator

  target 'ValidatorTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

    use_frameworks!
    pod 'RealmSwift'
  end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3' # or '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? The problem persists even if iOS version is changed to 10.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your pod repo. Try to setup again:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

Comment: yes there was.. thanks.. I used the following: rm -rf ~/.cocoapods; pod setup